# Opening .txt file when you open directory

Tags: files, directory

Is it possible to automatically open `*.txt` file as you open certain directory on Ubuntu?

We have a school assignment to make a text file to pop up when you open certain directory. For example, when you open your `Downloads` folder, you would see the `/ownfolder/example.txt` pop up.

Comment: Open the file in what? Open the directory in what? In a file manager? From the command line? Both? What directory? What text file? An existing file or do you want to create it? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you want to do.

Comment: OK, so what do you have so far? We won't do your homework for you, but we're happy to help if you're stuck on a specific part of it. Also, you still haven't explained what you mean by "open a directory". Are you referring to a GUI file manager? The command line?

Comment: We have this big assignment and i'm not even certain about this myself. We work mostly on terminal and using Kubuntu 14.04 LTS 

I'm trying to translate the assignment "Add x-directorys dir-settings file xxx.html so that it opens up if you go to the directory mentioned above." after that you make the xxx.html file to different directory example /www/test/xxx.html. 

I'm completely new to linux and just trying to learn.
We have lots of these little jobs to do and mostly i have figured them out, but this is like hitting a wall. I don't want straight answer but some tips to where to look.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your teacher then. Showing an html file in the terminal doesn't make much sense. I mean, it's possible with a text-based browser but why? You need to talk to your professor and ask them to clarify the task. For example, does this need to happen for all users? For your user only?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the original question and comments under the original question, this sounds like the goal may have more to do with the default directories that open when viewing a directory on a server through a browser (ie. web development). I may be completely wrong, however on this assumption:

Typically, web servers have some way to specify what the "default" file(s) are for a directory when a user opens it on a webserver (ex. http://www.google.com/chrome/ does not show a directory listing, but an actual webpage).

In Apache this might be through the *DirectoryIndex* directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

In NGINX this might be through the *index* directive:

```
index index.html index.htm;
```

In this example, a text file such as "example.txt" could be configured to open automatically by adding it to the respective line. This would, however, only show the contents of an "example.txt" file in the directory in which you were trying to open.